# Get result in 15 minutes interval in mysql

Tags: mysql, intervals

is there way where I can get the values of the day but in a 15 minutes interval, how should I do it? I'd want the result to look something like this:

```
+--------------------+-------+
| Date/Time          | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| 2014-01-01 8:00:10 |  10   |
| 2014-01-01 8:15:05 |  11   |
| 2014-01-01 8:30:04 |  24   | 
+--------------------+-------+
```

I was using this query but this gets the data for every hour and now i need the 15 min interval

```
SELECT x.* 
 FROM my_table x 
 JOIN 
    ( SELECT MAX(dt) max_dt 
        FROM my_table 
       GROUP BY DATE(dt),HOUR(dt)
    ) y
   ON y.max_dt = x.dt;
```

Comment: Please provide a better explanation of your problem. Preferably with a query you are using to get your data.

Comment: SELECT '2014-01-01 8:00:10' `Date\Time`, 10 Value UNION ... etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classify your timestamps by which portion of the hour they fall into (using integer division) then `group by` that classification.  So your inner query will look like:

```
SELECT MAX(dt) max_dt
FROM   my_table
GROUP  BY DATE(dt), HOUR(dt), MINUTE(dt) DIV 15
```

Comment: i needed to get the result in a 15 mins, 30 mins, 1 hour and 3 hours interval. It all worked until 1 hour interval and then for 3 hours I did DIV 180 and it didn't work, the interval is still 1 hour. is `DIV 180` correct?

Comment: `MINUTE(dt)` will never exceed 60, so `MINUTE(dt) DIV 180` will always give you 0.  If you want to group into hourly intervals, then you don't need to involve the minutes: `GROUP BY DATE(dt), HOUR(dt)` or `GROUP BY DATE(dt), HOUR(dt) DIV 3`.